# Self-employment solution moving from Canada to Austria

Tags: canada, taxes, austria

I am going to be moving from Canada to Austria next spring. I hold both an EU citizenship and a Canadian citizenship. I currently operate as a sole proprietor in Canada. One of my clients wants to keep working with me when I move to Austria, as I can work remotely as a software developer. **The catch is that he can only pay me if I invoice him as a Canadian company**.

I know that I will need to register as "self-employed" in Austria, so that I can pay into social security and health care. My main question is: **Can I continue to operate my sole proprietorship in Canada**? If I maintain a Canadian address, can I just continue to bill him as I have been doing in the past? Will I need to continue charging him GST, even though the work is being performed from outside Canada? What will be my tax obligations to Canada?

Comment: You can be "self-employed" in Austria and work as a contractor for your Canadian company.

Comment: "What will be my tax obligations to Canada?": It seems like you ought to ask a Canadian tax lawyer about this.

Comment: Yes, I have a contacted a few of them in Canada and am waiting on responses, but figured it was worth the question anyways in case someone has some relevant experience.